# Как отфильтровать выборку MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE s=1 ORDER BY id
```

Получил ряд id: `2,5,6,7,9,11,12,15,16,17,18,20`

Каким оператором MySQL можно вытащить из вышеуказанного ряда:
`2,5,6,7,12,15,16,17`?

Условие отбора - оставить числа, которые составляют пару - само число и оно же плюс 10.
То есть берем 2, прибавляем 10 (получается 12), в этом ряду есть число 12 - бинго! - обоих оставляем, далее берем 5 и ищем 5+10=15 - тоже есть оба двое - оставляем обоих и так далее, и вот мы подошли к 9 - прибавляем 10, получаем 19, такого числа нет, девятку удаляем.

Вот так не получилось:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE s=1 ORDER BY id) aa
WHERE ((aa.id MOD 10)=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать оператор `exists`:

```
SELECT id
FROM test t1
WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT id
          FROM test t2
          where t2.id in (t1.id + 10, t1.id - 10))
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57909e/5/0).

Comment: Может один exists `where t2.id in(t1.id+10, t1.id-10)`

Comment: @Mike да, точно! Спасибо, обновил ответ.

Comment: Mike, знаете зачем это правило было нужно? Я все еще в поисках ответа на ту тему про поиск свободного кубика 2х2 и больше, если интересно, то могу описать придуманный мною примерный алгоритм... Не тут наверное

Comment: А оператор IN разве полезен? Для первоначального варианта запроса (два экзиста) время выполнения 0,0006, для короткого 0,0017, это про сетку 10х10. И план выполнения для длинного вариант красивее выглядит, проход по 100 строкам без индекса и 2 раза по 10 строк с Using index condition, короткий вариант - два прохода по 100 строк без индексов.

Comment: @СергейВ. тут уже на ваше усмотрение) c `in` просто выглядит короче.

Comment: еще на примете имел ввиду оператор IF, тут он применим или идти читать доки внимательнее?

Comment: а как мне создать таблицу test внутри запроса из первого запроса в вопросе? т.е. вот эту выборку SELECT * FROM table WHERE s=1 ORDER BY id обрабатывать дальше ?

Comment: @СергейВ. `IF` тут не поможет, он скорей для вывода доп. столбца в `SELECT`. Замените мой test на ваш table и добавьте условие where s=1 и order by id

Comment: а в какую ветвь добавить? в самое начало добавляю - нет результатов, внутрь первой скобки - рез. неправильные

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46075/discussion-between-denis-and--).